# Basename puts single quotes around variable

Tags: macos, bash, quotes

I am writing a simple shell script to make automated backups, and I am trying to use basename to create a list of directories and them parse this list to get the first and the last directory from the list.

The problem is: when I use basename in the terminal, all goes fine and it gives me the list exactly as I want it. For example:

```
basename -a /var/*/
```

gives me a list of all the directories inside /var without the / in the end of the name, one per line.
BUT, when I use it inside a script and pass a variable to basename, it puts single quotes around the variable:

```
while read line; do
dir_name=$(echo $line)
basename -a $dir_name/*/ > dir_list.tmp
done < file_with_list.txt
```

When running with +x:

```
+ basename -a '/Volumes/OUTROS/backup/test/*/'
```

and, therefore, the result is not what I need.

Now, I know there must be a thousand ways to go around the basename problem, but then I'd learn nothing, right? ;)

How to get rid of the single quotes?
And if my directory name has spaces in it?

Comment: The trace output is somewhat arbitrary, intended just to show you what commands are executed. If you are getting the correct output in `dir_list.tmp`, I wouldn't worry about it. (Of course, if the contents of `dir_list.tmp` aren't what you want, you should post what you are getting and what you expect.) And FYI, `dir_name="$line"` is sufficient.

Comment: FYI: The `-a` and `-s` options to `basename` are not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html)-mandated and hence not universal.  That's not a problem while your script only runs on Mac OS X, but could be a portability liability.

Comment: What is the contents of `file_with_list.txt` ?  And what's the larger context for the code you've written?  (That is, what are you REALLY trying to do?)  This looks dangerously close to the [ParsingLS problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @chepner No, I am not getting the correct output. In console, I get the list I want. When running the script, I get only a * as content of the file, exactly what I get when running the command with the single quotes :(

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the info. I intend to use the same script in Linux, too. So I think I'll just abandon the basename.

Comment: @ghoti I am trying to write a simple backup script. It should get a directory listed in file_with_list.txt (/users, for example) and copy its contents to another location under /External/users/2012-07-01/, for example. If there are more than 7 copies under /External/users/, then it should delete the oldest and make a copy linked to the newest. The dir_list.txt should contain the date-named directories list, from wich I could get the first (oldest) and the last (newest), to delete the first and use the other as link in rsync. Got it?

Comment: @ghoti And, after reading the link you kindly posted, I have to agree that it is almost that :( Any idea?

Comment: @ghoti Although this is not the main question here, of course. The question relates to the single quotes in the basename command. Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: @DanielTrezub - none of that functionality (making dated directories, limiting to 7 copies) is in your question.  That sort of stuff can be handled more easily using other tools.  I've provided an answer below that is to THIS question, but I'd be happy to chime in on another question that looks at your overall goals instead.  (Just updating this question with the new requirements wouldn't be fair to the folks who have already spent some time answering your current question.)

Comment: @ghoti I will post another question about the backup system, it can be really useful. Thanks!

Comment: In a related note... And what about the single quotes in the basename command? :)

Answer (score 1):

If your directory name could include spaces, you need to quote the value of `dir_name` (which is a good idea for any variable expansion, whether you expect spaces or not).

```
while read line; do
  dir_name=$line
  basename -a "$dir_name"/*/ > dir_list.tmp
done < file_with_list.txt
```

(As jordanm points out, you don't need to quote the RHS of a variable assignment.)

Comment: While it never hurts to quote an expansion, word-splitting and globbing does not occur on the right side of an assignment. It is not needed here.

Comment: I got a little carried away there.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks a lot, I didn't know that. Let's go do some code cleaning! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your goal is to populate `dir_list.tmp` with a list of directories found under each directory listed in `file_with_list.txt`, this might do.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile=file_with_list.txt
outputfile=dir_list.tmp
rm -f "$outputfile"        # the -f makes rm fail silently if file does not exist

while read line; do

  # basic syntax checking
  if [[ ! ${line} =~ ^/[a-z][a-z0-9/-]*$ ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  # collect targets using globbing
  for target in "$line"/*; do
    if [[ -d "$target" ]]; then
      printf "%s\n" "$target" >> $outputfile
    fi
  done

done < $inputfile
```

As you develop whatever tool will process your `dir_list.tmp` file, be careful of special characters (including spaces) in that file.

Note that I'm using `printf` instead of `echo` so that targets whose first character is a hyphen won't cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```sh
while read; do
  find "$REPLY" >> dir_list.tmp
done < file_with_list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not use the baseline command, that is the main reason for this question :)